# Resetting a board from firmware running under anOS

Tags: c, freertos, firmware

I have a board running FreeRTOS. In main() I have hardware setup, task creation and parameter initialization, then finally the scheduler starts.

One of the tashs is a system monitor, in case something goes crazy. Problem is, how do I effectively restart the board from within a task? Language is C.

Comment: This question is totally hardware-specific.

Comment: Here's hoping you find someone who has ever used this hardware.

Comment: most boards have a register that can be used to reset the board.   The better ones have a register that you must read within a certain time frame to prevent the board from resetting ( a watchdog ).  Look at your board specs &| schematics.

Answer (score 0):

One answer I have discovered is to use freeRTOS [non-local Jumps](http://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/languages/c/non-local-jumps-setjmp-longjmp) (setjmp(), longjmp()). So it is not a totally hardware specific question

However, I will probably force the MCU h/w watchdog to time out